# I want "track changes" in Visual Studio to show changes that have not been commited to version control

Tags: visual-studio, version-control

"Track changes" in Visual Studio shows what lines have been edited in the current session (shown next to the scroll bar). But to me it is much more meaningful to see what lines have changed from the last version in version control.

In Eclipse this is possible. Is it possible to have the same in Visual Studio? I am using VisualHg, and Mercurial, but I suppose the same principle should apply for other version control solutions.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you want to see the changes next to the scroll bar such as the **track changes**.

I don't know how to achieve that. But I use TortoiseSVN and have an addon for VS (ankhSVN is the name, I guess), which lets me do a right click on the file and do **show changes**. There pretty sure is an equivalent addon for mercurial.

Maybe an addon such as Power Tools or VS Commands may provide a way of marking the lines you've changed next to the scroll bar.